# Add link to text - with the text in the link

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, addition, tracking

This is to tricky for me,..

..here we go. I have a `<table>` like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="cell0">01720007663795101</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now i would like to create a link arround the Text in the `<td>` like this:

```
<a href="https://tracking.dpd.de/cgi-bin/delistrack?pknr=01720007663795101&typ=1&lang=de">01720007663795101</a>
```

so you can see there are 4 steps to do.

1. grab the number in the `<td>` by classname
2. create a link arround the number, beginning with `<a href="https://tracking.dpd.de/cgi-bin/delistrack?pknr=`
3. append the number from `<td>` after `<a href="https://tracking.dpd.de/cgi-bin/delistrack?pknr=`
4. append the rest of the link **`&typ=1&lang=de">`** after `<a href="https://tracking.dpd.de/cgi-bin/delistrack?pknr=01720007663795101`

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/YuK6y/

```
$('.cell0').each(function(index, element){
    var tn = $(element).text();
    $(element).html('<a href="https://tracking.dpd.de/cgi-bin/delistrack?pknr='+tn+'&typ=1&lang=de">'+tn+'</a>');
});
```

Or, shorter:
http://jsfiddle.net/YuK6y/1/

```
$('.cell0').each(function(index, element){
    $(element).wrapInner('<a href="https://tracking.dpd.de/cgi-bin/delistrack?pknr='+$(element).text()+'&typ=1&lang=de" />');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var className = 'cell0';
td = $('td.' + className);
var link = '<a href="https://tracking.dpd.de/cgi-bin/delistrack?pknr=' + td.text() + '&typ=1&lang=de">' + td.text() + '</a>';
td.html(link);
```

See [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uXkP5/) -> update [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mikey/gYerx/)

Comment: This is not going to work if there is more than one cell: http://jsfiddle.net/uXkP5/1/

Comment: In that case the classname is not relevant and you have to iterate over the `td`s.
http://jsfiddle.net/Mikey/gYerx/